# Find repeating gps using regular expression

Tags: regex, csv, gps

I work with text files, and I need to be able to see when the gps (last 3 columns of csv) "hangs up" for more than a few lines.

So for example, usually, part of a text file looks like this:

```
5451,1667,180007,35.7397387,97.8161897,375.8
5448,1053z,180006,35.7397407,97.8161814,375.7
5444,1667,180005,35.7397445,97.8161674,375.6
5439,1668,180004,35.7397483,97.8161526,375.5
5435,1669,180003,35.7397518,97.8161379,375.5
5431,1669,180002,35.7397554,97.8161269,375.6
5426,1054z,180001,35.7397584,97.8161115,375.6
5420,1670,175959,35.7397649,97.8160931,375.9
```

But sometimes there is an error with the gps and it looks like this:

```
36859,1598,202603.00,35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
36859,1598,202608.00,35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
36859,1142z,202610.00,35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
36859,1597,202612.00,35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
36859,1597,202614.00,35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
36859,1596,202616.00,35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
36859,1595,202618.00,35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
```

I need to be able to figure out a way to search for matching strings of 7 different numbers, (the decimal portion of the gps) but so far I've only been able to figure out how to search for repeating #s or consecutive numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is error in NUMA string you posted as error?

Comment: @Saleem in the second example, the last three set of numbers repeat for all lines : 35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700

Comment: Well, your gps could be standstill. What NMEA string are you parsing?

Comment: See GPS NMEA sentences at http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm

Comment: @Saleem yes, it is at a standstill, the issue is that I need to find the spots in my text files that it does that....

Comment: Well, in this case regex can't help you alone. You need some kind of scripting or programming in appropriate language. e.g. Python, Java etc.

Comment: You could give `([^,]*(?:,[^,]*){2})\v(?:[^\v]*\1\v){3}` a try - it's checking for 4 consecutive occurences of the last 3 columns of your csv. - however it's not really speedy.

Comment: @SebastianProske, you are correct. But OP also mentioned **more than few lines** which is variable. it could be any number.

Comment: @Saleem - OP has to specify a number for **more than a few** anyways - the regex could be adjusted to that number. I doubt, that **pure** regex is the best way to achieve this goal, but it is possible.

Comment: I agree, for a quick hack a regex might be usefull to get results. For a product running, a regex solution is not the way to go here.

Comment: @AlexWien This isn't something we have to check often - there was an unusual error with a gps device during field data collecting, and I just needed a quick and dirty way to locate the issue.

Comment: Then it is fine, I would have opend it in excell, and wouldhave checked i fthe previous lat, lon is equal to current one. then I would have set a column "equal" to "1". And when this column is "1" I would have colored it red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to find such repetitions in an editor (such as Notepad++), you could use the following regex to find 4 or more repeating lines:

```
([^,]+(?:,[^,]+){2})\v+(?:(?:[^,]+,){3}\1(?:\v+|$)){3,}
```

To go a bit into detail

- `([^,]+(?:,[^,]+){2})\v+` is a group consisting of one or more non-commas followed by comma and another one or more non-commas followed by a vertical space (linebreak), that is not part of the group (e.g. 1,1,1\n)
- `(?:[^,]+,){3}` matches one or more non-commas followed by comma, three times (your columns that don't have to be considered)
- `\1` is a backreference to group 1, matching if it contains exactly the same as group 1
- `(?:\v+|$)` matches either another vertical whitespaces or the end of the text
- `{3,}` for 3 or more repetitions - increase it if you want more

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/jX6tM1/2) you can see, how it works

However, if you are using any programming language to check this, I wouldn't walk on the path of regex, as checking for those repetitions can be done a lot easier. Here is one example in Python, I hope you can adopt it for your needs:

```
oldcoords = [0,0,0]
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(r'C:\temp\gps.csv')]
for line in lines:
    gpscoords = line.split(',')[3:6]
    if gpscoords == oldcoords:
        repetitions += 1
    else:
        oldcoords = gpscoords
        repetitions = 0
    if repetitions == 4: #or however you define more than a few
        print(', '.join(gpscoords) + ' is repeated')
```

Comment: It looks like this one works! Thanks! the only weird thing is that if I increase it much higher than 10, it highlights the whole file, and says found first instance from top. (Using notepad ++.) Still a lot better than it was!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **perl**, and if I understood you:

> `perl -ne 'm/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$)/g; $current_line=$1; ++$line_number; if ($prev_line==$current_line){$equals++} else {if ($equals>=6){ print "Last three fields in lines ".($line_number-$equals-1)." to ".($line_number-1)." are equals to:\n$prev_line" } ; $equals=0}; $prev_line=$current_line' < onlyreplacethiswithyourfilepath` should do the trick.

Sample output:

> Last three fields in lines 1 to 7 are equals to:
>   35.8867316,99.2515545,555.700
>
> Last three fields in lines 16 to 22 are equals to:
>   37.8782116,99.7825545,572.810
>
> Last three fields in lines 31 to 44 are equals to:
>   36.6868916,77.2594245,581.358
>
> Last three fields in lines 57 to 63 are equals to:
>   35.5128764,71.2874545,575.631